# Restrict access to directories hosting different sites

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, directory

My hosting provider requires that my primary domain (let's call it `example.com`) points to my public_html root. I also own several other domains (let's call them `exampleA.com` and `exampleB.com`) that are hosted in sub-directories such that they can be accessed via `http://example.com/exampleA/` and `http://example.com/exampleB/`

I would like to restrict people from accessing these secondary sites in this way. Ideally, there will be no indication that the secondary sites are in any way related to the primary domain. How do I do this? Modify the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^exampleB/ - [R=404,L]
```

(Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386576/how-to-create-htaccess-to-block-access-to-a-subdirectory-that-hosts-a-separate-d/5386737#5386737) but I think mine is right whereas the first example in that one is wrong as it uses the wrong domain in `RewriteCond`. That should be enough, but you could try the other things in that question if it doesn't work.)

Comment: +1 But see a possible improvement on this here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/24363/3738 - this I believe stops unwanted paths appearing in the results in the first place.